# Wordpress overwritte php date hour in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

For my surprise today i see wordpress put bad the hour

In settings i have the hour of my country , France and City Paris

And today i try for create one function the php date function for show the date

```
<?php
echo date("dmY");
?>
```

For my surprise as i tell until , see wordpress change my php time and put day 19 and change the hour and no show the real time actually

If the same code insert in other site - no use wordpress - and the date show right , day 20

How it´s possible wordpress change native function of php and show when runnning this thedate of php , by other side in settings of wordpress i se utc different hour to local time , utc show 19 and local time show 20

I don´t understan all this .....

Thank´s for the help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the_date. Use [the_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time).